# How to wait for a return value from a function, which uses a tkinter GUI and takes input from user, before executing subsequent statements

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

So i'm creating a python project in which i'm extracting strings from a database using mysqlite. i call a function mark(diff) which extracts strings depending upon value of input by user through a tkinter OptionMenu and appends strings to a list and returns them back to the "question" function.

The problem is that after i call mark(diff) from "question" function it does not wait for the mark() function to complete and read inputs, instead it continues next statement of execution

i read about the after() method in tkinter somewhere but i wasn't sure whether it applied here or how it should be applied

```
 def mark(diff):
    diff=diff.upper()
    win=Tk()
    win.title("Question Paper Generator")
    win.configure(background='#ECECEC')
    win.geometry('650x500')
    j=0
    t1 = StringVar(win)
    t1.set("THEORITICAL"
    obj1 = []

    def clicked1():
        t11=t1.get()

        sql_id_cmd1 = ("SELECT MAX(ID) FROM "+diff+"4"+str(t11))
        cur.execute(sql_id_cmd1)
        data1=cur.fetchone()
        i1 = data1[0]
        rand1 = random_num_gen(i1)

        sql_in_cmd1 = ("SELECT QS FROM "+diff+"4"+str(t11)+" WHERE "+"ID = "+str(rand1[j]))
        cur.execute(sql_in_cmd1)
        obj1.append(list(cur.fetchone()))

        return obj1

    l4 = Label(win, font="SF\Mono 16 bold", text = "Enter Question Type",background='#ECECEC',justify='left')
    l4.grid(column=0, row=1,padx=20,pady=10)

    frame5=Frame(win)
    frame5.grid(column=0,row=2,padx=0,pady=10)
    optionm = OptionMenu(frame5,t1,"THEORITICAL","PROOF","MCQ","NUMERICAL")
    optionm.grid(column=0, row=0)

    frame4=Frame(win)
    frame4.grid(column=0,row=11,padx=0,pady=10)
    btn = Button(frame4, text="Submit",command=clicked1)
    btn.grid(column=0, row=0)


def questions(diff):
    obj1=[]
    obj2=[]
    obj3=[]
    obj1=mark("Easy")
    obj2=mark("Easy")
    obj3=mark("Easy")
    pdf_gen(obj1,obj2,obj3)
```

the mark() function returns a list into obj1 but instead of waiting for input from user it immediately executes the pdf_gen function with obj1,obj2,ob3 as None type
the program should wait for the returned list into obj1,obj2,obj3 and then only call pdf_gen()

**EDIT -**

i tried using button as suggested but error still persists

```
def questions(diff):

        obj1=[]
        obj2=[]
        obj3=[]

        obj1=mark("Easy")
        obj2=mark("Easy")
        obj3=mark("Easy")

        if obj1 is not None and obj2 is not None and obj3 is not None:
            win=Tk()
            win.title("Question Paper Generator")
            win.configure(background='#ECECEC')
            win.geometry('650x500')
            frame=Frame(win)
            frame.grid(column=0,row=3,padx=0,pady=10)
            addbutton=Button(frame,text="Generate")
            addbutton.config(height = 2, width = 15,bg='#ECECEC',justify='left',bd='5',relief='raised',command=lambda:pdf_gen(obj1,obj2,obj3) )
            addbutton.grid(column=0,row=20)
            win.mainloop()
```

Here it altogether skips the statements inside the if statement and terminates

If i remove the if statement and directly create a button the original problem persists and obj1 , obj2, obj3 are passed on as None to pdfgen even after the button "Generate" is clicked

Comment: (Syntax (and spelling) look dubious around `t1.set("THEORITICAL"`. In a similar vein, I'd advise to use abbrev. judiciously in source code - *diff*, for one, might easily be from *difference*.) You can make code snippets stand out as such enclosing them in `\`\`` "backticks".

Comment: Actually your `mark()` function will always return None as there is no return statement at the end of the function.  Also the return statement in `clicked1()` is useless in your case.  Try adding `win.mainloop()` and `return obj1` at the end of `mark()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Your achitecture is not good. You create obj1/2/3 then apply a function. But your obj1/2/3 are "**actually**" considered as ready **after that the user click**. So you are applying a function on object that are not ready.

There are 2 solutions :

```
obj1=...
obj2=...
obj3=...
button_pdf_gen = Button(..., ...,command=pdf_gen)
```

*The user must click on the button to create the pdf. So you need to check in pdf_gen that all object are ready.*

**Or**

In def clicked1:

```
...
if obj1 is ready and obj2 is ready obj3 is ready:
    then pdf_gen()
```

*When all obj1/2/3 is ready it will call pdf_gen.*

Comment: i tried your suggestion but doesnt seem to work. See Edit^

Comment: Because obj1/2/3 are not None -> they are lists [ ]. Try that : a = []
print(a is None) It returns false because empty list are not None. May be you should check the length of obj1/2/3.

Comment: ok i thought they were same thing. I tried using len() but im getting ```if len(obj1)!=0 and len(obj2)!=0 and len(obj3)!=0:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()```

Comment: OK, because mark() returns nothing. obj1/2/3=mark() Then obj1/2/3=None. You should use MCU to avoid that, making difference between object, controller & view. The idea should be : User click on the view, that control the object. Something like that : create obj1/2/3; user clicks on button to update obj1/2/3. It is really strange to have def in def (clicked in mark). Mark should be called by click.